# How to retrieve and print the following data

Tags: java

[arraylist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Insd.jpg)

I have data in this format, its a arraylist of object itemdata.

```
static class itemData{
    private String itemName;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private int couponCode;
    private int couponId;
  }
  public List<itemData> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

below fuction is how i am storing the data

```
 public couponInterface addItems(String itemName, int quantity, double price,
                                  int couponCode, int couponId) {

    itemData t = new itemData();
    t.itemName = itemName;
    t.quantity = quantity;
    t.price = price;
    t.couponCode = couponCode;
    t.couponId = couponId;
    itemList.add(t);
    return this;
  }
```

how do i retrieve the data and print it?

the current output shows - couponAbstract$itemData@31f924f5

Comment: either override `toString()` method of `itemData` class or just print each property

Comment: i don't have toString method.

Comment: Override the java.lang.toString() method.

Comment: how to override it?

Comment: Put `@Override
    public String toString(){
        return literally anything;
    }` literally anywhere (I don't think the @Override annotation is necessary though) You can put anything inside that toString() method, i.e. return "" or each variable combined into a long string.

Comment: Don't you have getters and setters? Though if you want to print everything in one go `toString()` is probably best option.

Comment: i wrote getters in class, how do i access it a concrete class which implements this method which lies in abstract class

Comment: solved the issue

Comment: Okay, I believe my answer fits the requirements in your question. Please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here are ways to successfully print your object.

Not overriding toString, and accepting the input it gives. (What you are currently doing)

Overriding `java.lang.Object.toString();` is another. (Just put a toString method anywhere in your class that returns string as your class is an object)

Gathering your variables by various means and printing them off.

Comment: I vote for choice #3